# No sound on linux

Tags: opensuse, gnome3, alsa

Have no sound on my system (opensuse 13.1 | gnome 3.12).

```
alsamixer 
ALSA lib control.c:953:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL default
cannot open mixer: No existe el fichero o el directorio
```

Some data to add:

```
sudo /sbin/lspci  | grep Audio
00:01.1 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Wrestler HDMI Audio
00:14.2 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] SBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA) (rev 40)

cat /proc/asound/cards
 0 [Generic        ]: HDA-Intel - HD-Audio Generic
                      HD-Audio Generic at 0xf0444000 irq 41
 1 [SB             ]: HDA-Intel - HDA ATI SB
                      HDA ATI SB at 0xf0440000 irq 16
```

Gnome does not see the cards :(

```
aplay -l
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
ALSA lib control.c:953:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:0
aplay: device_list:277: control open (0): No existe el fichero o el directorio
ALSA lib control.c:953:(snd_ctl_open_noupdate) Invalid CTL hw:1
aplay: device_list:277: control open (1): No existe el fichero o el directori
```

So how can I make it work?

**Add this at 8/10/2014 at 16:06 UYT**

```
@bottle:~> ls -l /dev/snd
total 0
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root       80 oct  8 13:30 by-path
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  4 oct  8 13:30 controlC0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  8 oct  8 13:30 controlC1
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  3 oct  8 13:30 hwC0D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  7 oct  8 13:30 hwC1D0
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  2 oct  8 13:30 pcmC0D3p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  6 oct  8 13:30 pcmC1D0c
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  5 oct  8 13:30 pcmC1D0p
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116,  1 oct  8 13:30 seq
crw-rw----+ 1 root audio 116, 33 oct  8 13:30 timer
```

[image: the only thing that opensuse shows me]

```
 YaST2 - sound @ bottle

  Sound Configuration                                


  Index         Card Model                                                         
  Not configuredATI Technologies Inc                                               
  Not configuredSBx00 Azalia (Intel HDA)                                           











  ATI Technologies Inc                                                              
                                                                                    ↓

  [Add][Edit][Delete]                                                         [Other↓]


 F1 Help  F3 Add  F4 Edit  F5 Delete  F9 Cancel  F10 OK
```

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l /dev/snd/`?

Comment: ok I added that!

Comment: So is your user a member of the `audio` group? (This should have happened automatically.)

Comment: `marcelo@bottle:~> id
uid=1000(marcelo) gid=100(users) grupos=100(users),481(libvirt),482(qemu),483(kvm),486(vboxusers)` nope i'm not in audio gruop I check also on another machine and I'm not in audio in that machine too.

Comment: Check the file Access Control List on each of the files in /dev/snd.  Your User should be listed.  Also chmod o+t /dev/snd/*

Comment: [check this](http://askubuntu.com/a/526586/283843)

Comment: thanks but `alsa` as it is noting to me `alsaconf` , `alsa_in`,`alsa-init`, `alsamixer`, `alsa_out`, `alsactl`, `alsa-info.sh`, `alsaloop`, `alsamixergui`, `alsaucm`. Will read a little more about this. :)

Comment: By the way, what does YaST say when you go to sound? Although lacking [super cow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aptitude_%28software%29#Easter_egg) powers, YaST (in OpenSuSE) is pretty powerful.

Comment: ok added a copy of yast on xterm...

Answer (score 1):

Had a similar issue these days.
Installing `pulseaudio` and `pavucontrol` solved the problem for me.
After the installation you have to run pavucontrol and configure your sound cards once.

Comment: already do that. had no luck with that approach.

Comment: did you try all the approaches recommended in [this article](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:Audio_troubleshooting)?

Comment: yes! follow all the tips but get nothing